# How to create signup test that works every time without changing user signup data?

Tags: postman

I created a Sign Up test in postman and linked it to my website Sign Up endpoint.

However, because Postman uses this test to actually create a user, I can only use it once. (If I want this test to work again, I need to change the email and name of the created user.)

I wonder is there a way to make this test work repeatedly?

Sign up endpoint is
`http://localhost:8000/auth/users/`

user test data:

```
{
    "email": "newuser@gmail.com",
    "name": "newuser",
    "password": "testuser12345",
    "re_password": "testuser12345"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
    "email": "{{$randomEmail}}",
    "name": "{{$randomFirstName}}",
    "password": "testuser12345",
    "re_password": "testuser12345"
}
```

You can use postman dynamic variable,

https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/variables-list/